# Why is my timezone not being set in Cypress with moment-timezone library?

Tags: automation, timezone, cypress, moment-timezone

Need a way to set Browser's Timezone in Cypress

I have used moment-timezone library

1. Added in support>index.js
   `const moment = require('moment-timezone');`
2. Added TZ env variable in my cypress.config.js

```
"env": {
      "TZ": "America/New_York"
    },
```

3. set the timezone to in by beforeEach hook

```
beforeEach(() => {
 moment.tz.setDefault('America/New_York');
})
```

4. it block contains the assertion
   `const browserTimeZone = moment.tz.guess(); expect(browserTimeZone).to.equal('America/New_York');`

But it is not setting up the timezone, the assertion is failing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8IHf.png)